# DataServiceConfiguration inaccessible?

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5, wcf-data-services

The following code worked previous to the Vs2010 upgrade...

```
using System.Data.Services;
namespace Nla.Dashboard.Web.Services
{
public class DashboardDataService : DataService<NlaPrimaryEntities>
{
    // This method is called only once to initialize service-wide policies.
    public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
    {
       etc...
```

The problem is that now I get these errors...

> 'System.Data.Services.DataServiceConfiguration'
>   is inaccessible due to its protection
>   level

and...

> Inconsistent accessibility: parameter
>   type
>   'System.Data.Services.DataServiceConfiguration'
>   is less accessible than method...

It is possible I am referencing the wrong library, this service is asp.net 3.5 under VS2010 hosting code originally built in vs2008 for ado.net data services 1.5 ctp2.

Any help is welcome!

Ken

Answer (score 1):

When you are running under VS 2010, what's the target framework? My guess is even when you are running on VS 2010, you are targetting 3.5 version of the framework and you do not have the "Data Services update for 3.5 SP1" RTM installed.

You can install the RTM version of the update from the link in the blog below: [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/astoriateam/data-services-update-for-net-3-5-sp1-now-available-for-download).

Hope this helps.

Thanks
Pratik

Comment: For the lazy - Windows 7 and up [download here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=79d7f6f8-d6e9-4b8c-8640-17f89452148e&displaylang=en)